# Difference in date time

Tags: shell

I have 2 variables.

```
GMDCOMTM which stores the date time Tue Oct  1 13:32:40 2013
GMDRRSTM which stores the date time Tue Oct  2 23:35:33 2013
```

How do I calculate the difference between the 2 variables in hh:mm:ss format and store
it in 3rd variable.? I dont want to use AWK, SED or PERL. I want to use simple shell
script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert dates to `%s  --->   seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

```
$ date -d"Tue Oct  2 23:35:33 2013" "+%s"
1380749733
```

So the thing is to get the difference in seconds between both dates using `bc` as calculator:

```
$ d1="Tue Oct  1 13:32:40 2013"
$ d2="Tue Oct  2 23:35:33 2013"
$ echo $(date -d"$d2" "+%s") - $(date -d"$d1" "+%s") | bc
122573
```

Then you can get it into hours, days, with the [great function Stéphane Gimenez indicates in UNIX & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27014/40596):

```
$ displaytime 122573
1 days 10 hours 2 minutes and 53 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C=$(date -d "Tue Oct  1 13:32:40 2013" +%s)
R=$(date -d "Tue Oct  2 23:35:33 2013" +%s)
T=$(date --date=@$((R-C))  +%H:%M:%S)
```

Comment: Note the date is bigger than one day, so you need to add extra fields in your date format to show them. Apart from that, it is a really good and short answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm normal using a custom made function to do the calculations. It may be long way but it will definitely work on all UNIX and Linux based systems. Following the code block.

```
time_diff(){
    foodate1=$1
    foodate2=$2
    foosecvall=`echo $foodate1 | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'`
    foosecval2=`echo $foodate2 | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'`
    foodiffsec=$((foosecvall-foosecval2));

    s=$foodiffsec
    h=$((s/3600));
    s=$((s-$((h*3600))));
    m=$((s/60));
    s=$((s-$((m*60))));
    footmstm=$h":"$m":"$s
}
```

Place the above code in your script and then call the function like follows.

```
TIME1="10:12:14"
TIME2="12:15:14"

time_diff $TIME2 $TIME1

echo $footmstm
```